# Run code alongside a Flask application

Tags: python, flask

I've written a web interface for my python application. This functions beautifully when running `export FLASK_APP=main.py` followed by `flask run`. Now I want the actual application to also run, so the interface can be useful.

The code below is my main.py, where I call the flask applications factory function.

```
from webinterface import create_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_app()
    while(True):
        # Some code logging different things
```

I want to do stuff inside the infinite loop, however when I try to run the application, it either runs only the web interface or the infinte loop, depending if I start it using `flask run` or `python main.py`.

How do I best accomplish this?

Comment: why do you need this `while` loop exactly ? if it's about logging, you have a bunch of solutions with the `logging` module

Comment: @PRMoureu It's for logging from external components. Temperature sensors etc. and logging that into a database, it needs to run permanently.

Comment: WSGI applications are not designed to run other tasks in parallel. It might work with the development server but in a production setup you will get into troubles.

Comment: @KlausD. So would you recommend having to separate python scripts running, in order to accomplish the task? One handling the web interface, and one handling all the logging and measuring tasks?

Comment: Yes, that sounds much better.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, and sometime convenient, to run Flask in a thread off of a foreground application. There is a trick, a big pitfall, and a constraint.

The constraint is that this is something you'll want to do in a "safe" environment (e.g. on your laptop to server a local browser, or on your home intranet), as it involves running the development server, which is something you don't want to be doing in a hostile environment. You also can't use automatic page reloading (but you can enable debug).

The pitfall is that if the UI is sharing any non-trivial state (including dicts) with the foreground app, you'll need to use a shared `threading.Lock()` to guard access such that only one thread at a time is reading or writing data.

The trick is to inject a reference to shared state into the app's config after you create it but before you start it, doing something like:

```
def webserver(state):
    app.config['STATE'] = state
    # If running on, say, a Raspberry Pi, use 0.0.0.0 so that
    # you can connect to the web server from your intranet.
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', use_reloader=False, debug=True)

def main():
    state = SharedState()
    web_thread = threading.Thread(target=webserver, args=(state,))
    web_thread.start()

    state.set('counter' 0)
    while True:
        # Do whatever you want in the foreground thread
        state.set('counter', state.get('counter') + 1)

class SharedState():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.state = dict()

    def get(self, key):
        with self.lock:
            return self.state.get(key)

    def set(self, key, value):
        with self.lock:
            self.state[key] = value
```

Then, from within Flask view functions, do something like

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    state = app.config['STATE']
    counter = state.get(counter)
    return render_template("index.html", counter=counter)
```